# UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication is nil on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios13

When use third-party login ,in the function 
`func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`, the **UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication** is nil on iOS 13.

Why? And how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: In iOS 13 it is the scene delegate that is called, not the app delegate.

Comment: It might be that you need to use the Scene Delegate instead on iOS 13.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508764

Comment: @matt the func `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` is called, it just the key **UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication** is nil.

I tried add `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)` but it is not called.

Comment: Because `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` is called instead (at launch).

Comment: @matt I confirmed to the protocol **UISceneDelegate** and but func `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` isn't called. 

It remains called `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`