# Flutter IOS AppLifecycleState

Tags: ios, flutter

flutter app in IOS device, while recording audio if we get call, recording should be paused and once call is over then either we should ask to save the recording by clicking on some button or should get save automatically. For this we are using AppLifecycleState concept of WidgetsBindingObserver. Used initstate, dispose and didChangeAppLifecycleState but didChangeAppLifecycleState is not triggering when we get call in IOS device... this is working fine in Android device and also older version IOS device like 8Plus where app goes to background when we get the call. Is any one faced same issue or got the resolution for this let us know... looking forward resolution for this issue...

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508764/app-delegate-methods-arent-being-called-in-ios-13

Comment: thanks for the sharing the details, this talks about in IOS native code but I need in flutter development

Answer (score 0):

this is resolved using flutter_phone_state package, using this package call status can be tracked like inbound, connected, disconnected (RawEventType.inbound, RawEventType.disconnected, etc..,) and based on requirement respective functionality can rewritten in respective section.